# How to speed up iteration while working on a data-frame with over 5 million observations in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to generate values for over 7 variables across millions of observations  and it's taking forever when I write a for loop to achieve this. Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve. In this case it's fast since it has only a few thousand observations:

```
# Load dplyr


library(tidyverse)
set.seed(50)

df <- data_frame(SlNo = 1:2000,
                 Scenario = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4),500),
                 A = round(rnorm(2000, 11, 6)),
                 B = round(rnorm(2000, 15, 4))) %>%
      arrange(Scenario) 

#splitting data-frame to add multiple rows in the data-frame

df<- df %>% split(f = .$Scenario) %>%
  map_dfr(~bind_rows(tibble(Scenario = 0), .x)) 

#observations for certain variables in the newly added rows have specific values

df <- df %>% mutate(C = if_else(Scenario != 0, 0, 4),
                    E = if_else(Scenario != 0, 0, 6))

for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {

df$C[i] <- if_else(df$Scenario[i] != 0, (1-0.5) * df$C[i-1] + 3 + 2 + df$B[i] + df$E[i-1],
              df$C[i])
df$E[i] <- if_else(df$Scenario[i] != 0, df$C[i] + df$B[i] - 50, df$E[i])


}

df

# A tibble: 2,004 x 6
   Scenario  SlNo     A     B     C      E
      <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1        0    NA    NA    NA   4     6   
 2        1     1    14    19  32     1   
 3        1     5     1    13  35    -2   
 4        1     9    17    20  40.5  10.5 
 5        1    13     8     7  42.8  -0.25
 6        1    17    10    16  42.1   8.12
 7        1    21     9    12  46.2   8.19
 8        1    25    14    18  54.3  22.3 
 9        1    29    14    15  69.4  34.4 
10        1    33     4    17  91.1  58.1 
# ... with 1,994 more rows
```

I'd like to produce similar results quickly while working with larger data frames. I appreciate any help on this. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Could you write out what your aim is in words? I think it makes it faster to think of a solution rather than trying to figure out from your code. Also have you looked at using `data.table` and replacing the for loop with some faster method?

Comment: The data-frame I am working on contains millions of rows & 7 variables, out of which I need to iteratively calculate the values for three variables. In this example there are 4 scenarios and the code is written to calculate values for var. C & E for each scenario. The 1st observation of C & E for each scenario is assigned a specific value.  The values of each subsequent observation for each of these variables, depend on the preceding values of the same variable i.e C[i] value depends on C[i-1] and E[i-1]. The for loop written to achieve this is very slow when applied to a DF with over 5M obs..

Comment: This looks it's just algebra, though complicated. If you write it out, I bet you can come up with something that just uses `cumsum` and `lag`.

Comment: It would have easier if you have written your formula in words too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tidyverse` you may use `purrr::accumulate` like this

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(50)

df <- data.frame(SlNo = 1:2000,
                 Scenario = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4),500),
                 A = round(rnorm(2000, 11, 6)),
                 B = round(rnorm(2000, 15, 4))) %>%
  arrange(Scenario)

df %>%
  nest(data = B) %>%
  group_by(Scenario) %>%
  mutate(new = accumulate(data, 
                          .init = tibble(C = 4, E = 6),
                          ~ tibble(C = (1 -0.5)* .x$C + 5 + .y$B + .x$E,
                                   E = 0.5 * .x$C + 5 + .x$E + 2 * .y$B - 50
                                   )
                          )[-1]
         ) %>% ungroup %>%
  unnest_wider(data) %>%
  unnest_wider(new)

#> # A tibble: 2,000 x 6
#>     SlNo Scenario     A     B     C     E
#>    <int>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1        1    14    19  32    1   
#>  2     5        1     1    13  35   -2   
#>  3     9        1    17    20  40.5 10.5 
#>  4    13        1     8     7  42.8 -0.25
#>  5    17        1    10    16  42.1  8.12
#>  6    21        1     9    12  46.2  8.19
#>  7    25        1    14    18  54.3 22.3 
#>  8    29        1    14    15  69.4 34.4 
#>  9    33        1     4    17  91.1 58.1 
#> 10    37        1    13    15 124.  88.7 
#> # ... with 1,990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to transition to `data.table`, or `dtplyr`, which could be tricky in figuring out how to adapt `cumsum` and `lag` to your needed output, you could adapt your loop to be run in parallel, here an example of the code:

```
#install.packages("foreach")
#install.packages("doParallel")

# Loading libraries

library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(50)

df <- data_frame(SlNo = 1:2000,
                 Scenario = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4),500),
                 A = round(rnorm(2000, 11, 6)),
                 B = round(rnorm(2000, 15, 4))) %>%
      arrange(Scenario) 

#splitting data-frame to add multiple rows in the data-frame

df<- df %>% split(f = .$Scenario) %>%
  map_dfr(~bind_rows(tibble(Scenario = 0), .x)) 

#observations for certain variables in the newly added rows have specific values

df <- df %>% mutate(C = if_else(Scenario != 0, 0, 4),
                    E = if_else(Scenario != 0, 0, 6))


# Setting up the cores
n.cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1
my.cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(
        n.cores, 
        type = "PSOCK",
        .packages="dplyr"
)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = my.cluster)

# Run the foreach loop in parallel
foreach(
        i = 2:nrow(df2), 
        .combine = 'rbind'
) %dopar% {
        df$C[i] <- if_else(df$Scenario[i] != 0, (1-0.5) * df$C[i-1] + 3 + 2 + df$B[i] + df$E[i-1],
                           df$C[i])
        df$E[i] <- if_else(df$Scenario[i] != 0, df$C[i] + df$B[i] - 50, df$E[i])
}
df
# stop the cluster
parallel::stopCluster(cl = my.cluster)
```

This should speed up your code significantly. However, not that time execution differences with parallel are evident over larger datasets, with small dataset it can actually take a bit more time to execute.